# Compose Observable from two dependant

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

I need to compose one Observable from values of two another Observables. The answer is *zip* operator. But my case is more complicated.
I have an *id* of A.

```
A {id, name, idOfRelatedB} //first observable
B {...} // second
```

So, in  order to get B, I need to get A before to retrieve an id of B. And finally I need to return an Observable with A and B.
How to deal with that in RX.

My unsuccessful solution in angular/typescript:

```
    @Injectable()
export class StrategyResolver implements Resolve<StrategyWithSourceCode> {
  constructor(private strategyService: StrategyService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    const strategyId = route.paramMap.get('strategyId');
    let sourceCodeObs: Observable<SourceCode>;
    let strategy: Strategy;

    this.strategyService.getStrategy(parseInt(strategyId)).subscribe(value => {
      strategy = value;
      sourceCodeObs = this.strategyService.getStrategySource(parseInt(strategyId), strategy.sourceCodeId);
    });
    return zip(of(strategy), sourceCodeObs, (v1: Strategy, v2: SourceCode) => ({v1, v2}));
  }
}
```

Upd: correct solution with help of user madjaoue (thanks for him) with any specific of rxjs 6.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    const strategyId = route.paramMap.get('strategyId');
    return this.strategyService.getStrategy(parseInt(strategyId)).pipe(
      concatMap(strategy => {
        let sourceCodeObs = this.strategyService.getStrategySource(parseInt(strategyId), strategy.sourceCodeId);
        return zip(of(strategy), sourceCodeObs, (v1: Strategy, v2: SourceCode) => ({v1, v2}));
      })
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't so far from the answer. This is a slight modification of your code that does what you want.

```
const strategyObs = this.strategyService.getStrategy(parseInt(strategyId));

// use concatMap to combine two streams
strategyObs.concatMap(strategy => {
  let sourceCodeObs = this.strategyService.getStrategySource(parseInt(strategyId), strategy.sourceCodeId);

  // zip the response of the first service with the second 
  return zip(Observable.of(strategy), sourceCodeObs)
});
.subscribe( ([A, B]) => ...)
```

Note that you can replace `concatMap` by other operators like `switchMap` , `mergeMap` or `exhaustMap` for example. All will combine your streams, but not in the same way. Please check that `concatMap` is suitable for your case.

Comment: It seems like I've forgotten to mention one critical thing: this method should return an Observable. If you familiar with Angular2  - this logic I need for Router resolver method.

Comment: It does return an observable (that's why you can subscribe). However, the value streamed by the observable is an array. Is that what you want ?

Comment: The method gets strategyId and should return an Observable with Strategy and its SourceCode.

Comment: I don"t get your problem. The answer I posted actually returns an observable, to which you can subscribe the same way I wrote : `subscribe( ([A,B]) => ...)`. The value returned by the `Observable` is a list that contains two elements, so [A,B]. A is `strategy`, which obviously is the result of `getStrategy`, B is the `sourceCode` returned by `getStrategySource`. So this actually returns an Observable with Strategy and its SourceCode.

Comment: Could it possibly be that you don't want a list ? You want merge A and B into one single object ?

Comment: I've done =) and append correct solution to my first post. Thank you very much!